# xlWings issue in Citrix Xen Environment

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have setup xlWings to use Python in Microsoft Excel in my Citrix server.  I have tested by running the excel and wrote a simple Python script and it works fine; however, after I have published the excel sheet and opened the excel spreadsheet through remote Citrix website.  Ran same Python script, but gave me an error, "#ERR: Could not Create Python process."  Can anyone provide solution for this?

Many thanks in advance,

Bill